# Image editing no longer works after moving to a new server

Tags: images

I moved to a new EC2 server (Linux 2) and have installed everything I thought was needed. However, now when I login to the back end of my Wordpress sites, I am no longer able to "edit" (crop, resize, etc.) images - like a featured image. No image is shown when I click "Edit Image". I have tried turning off all plugins... no change. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I forget exactly how that works but it might depend on the image library you've got set up with PHP. Can you check in Tools, Site Health, Info, Media Handling?

Comment: It might also be on-disk permissions, in that WordPress might not have permission to write to the file you're trying to crop.

Comment: The issue was the missing GD module!  Thanks to you (@Rup) for pointing that out.  Worked fine!  If you want to post that as the answer, I'll accept it so you'll get credit for the correct answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: @LeeFuller can you post that as an answer/solution rather than in the comments? You don't get points/reputation or perks for comment upvotes and the site will keep suggesting this question trying to find you a solution

Comment: @TomJNowell, thanks.  I was giving Rup the option to answer it and get credit.  I don't need the credit.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments this was because the new site was missing both of the supported image editing tools, GD and ImageMagick, as PHP modules. (Either one will work - you don’t need both.) The 'Edit Image' button appears if at least one of the installed tools supports the current file type.

You can check under Tools, Site Health, Info, Media Handling to see which if either you have installed.

Comment: To be clear, I did not need to install ImageMagick.  I only installed GD - and it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry yes I meant either one would work. You don’t need both, no.